# JSON Post data request in JMeter

Tags: rest, jmeter, load-testing

I have a rest web-service which accepts JSON post data but for requesting any API url, we need to pass `access_token`.
So my post data is a JSON data and `access_token` is passed as query string.

- Problem:

  As per my exploration i have not found any way to send request which can have JSON post data and also accepts Query String from the HTTP-URL-REWRITING in JMeter.
- Actual Request:

  ```
  POST http://<domain>/webapp/service/document/save    
  POST data: { node = '1'}token_XXXXXX
  [no cookies]    
  Request Headers: Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 980 Host: localhost User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)
  ```

Below is the expected request data.

- Expected Request:

  ```
  POST http://<domain>/webapp/service/document/save?access_token=token_XXXXXX    
  POST data: { node = '1'}   
  [no cookies]  
  Request Headers: Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 980 Host: localhost User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)
  ```

How should i configure it in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In path field, add access_token like this:

- path?access_token=${value extracted by regexp}

And use raw post body for the JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for this .

Instead of using Header Manager , I have used BeanShell preprocessor where I just removed the argument from the aeguments availble in Beanshell preprocessor and addded the QueryString to path of the request using setPath() method available in BeanShell Preprocessor .

```
Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
String access_token = sampler.getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap().get("access_token");
arguments.removeArgument("access_token");
String path = sampler.getUrl() + "?access_token=" + access_token;
sampler.setPath(path);
```

This code solved my problem.
Alternate is HeaderManager. Already Answered by @PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE

Comment: yes.. but if i have just modified the post-data content using HeaderManger then... still i need to append my access_token to url.. thats y i preffered removing argument & appending querystring to url

Comment: It seems I had misunderstood your question, I updated my andwer